# Tried code from Microsoft.Bot.Sample.AadV2Bot but even locally get AADSTS50011 (reply url doesn't match)

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I've integrated the Code from Microsoft.Bot.Sample.AadV2Bot in my own bot but the GetTokenDialog call always results in error "AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: 'MYBOTSAPPID'"

As far as I understood, I do not have to register my bot in Azure Portal under "Azure Active Directory" but setup the Reply URL in the application registration Portal (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) - Correct?

But whatever values I enter here, it won't work, neither locally via Emulator nor via Web. Furthermore, in MS Teams the signin Dialog does not work at all.

I've already tried these reply URLs without success:

https://MYBOTSNAME.azurewebsites.net, http://localhost:3978 and https://localhost:44362

I also tried to extend these with /api/messages, /signin-oidc and several other combinations, all without success.

The mentioned sample solution also does not include more keys than ConnectionName, MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword in web.config, so I haven't got a clue which redirect URI is taken on runtime.

In Azure Portal I've created an Azure Active Directory V2 Connection on my bot and entered my bot's Microsoft App ID in the field "Client ID" and Microsoft App Password in the field "Client Secret" - is this correct?

Any hint what I might have done wrong is VERY welcome!!

Answer (score 1):

I finally could solve the Reply URL mismatch problem myself. Had to enter this Reply URL on my app in the application Registration Portal to make it work locally, via Emulator:

https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect

Still, the authentification Dialog (GetTokenDialog class from Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs) doesn't popup when I use MS Teams as channel.

Does anyone have an idea what could help?

Comment: Can you please post a new question for your follow up question

Comment: thanks for the hint - have posted a new Question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50828452/using-ms-teams-as-channel-authentification-dialog-gettokendialog-class-from-mi